# How to re generate Facebook app's long lived access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token, facebook-permissions

I am trying to r generate long lived access token for my app. I created long lived access token manually using explorer and it expired after 60 days. Is there a way to auto regenerate access token without login flow using app id & secret id?

Comment: no, of course you cannot auto-regenerate a token without user interaction, that would be weird. what token are you talking about anyway? there are different ones.

Comment: I am talking about user token

Answer (score 1):

You cannot auto-regenerate a (User) Token without user interaction. 60 days is the maximum lifespan of a User Token. If it would be possible to auto-generate a User Token, it would not even make sense to set a limited lifespan.